# Como puedo evitar que al llamar un fragment, este no se vuelva a crear, sino que muestre los datos que tenia desde el principio?

Tags: java, android-studio, android-fragment, android-volley

Estoy haciendo un proyecto en Android Studio, requiero que, en un navigation drawer, al seleccionar un fragment que ya se había cargado y vaciado información en el (es el primer fragment que aparece, en el evento onCreate), se evite la tarea de volverse a crear y volver a hacer la consulta de información para llenarla, cuando el usuario lo vuelve a seleccionar . Esto es para ahorrarle datos móviles al Usuario, por que la información que se descarga ahí es algo pesada. Algo como el  evento OnResume() del activity común.

Comment: Mira [ask] <- ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] <- ACA para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Siempre pero siempre debes colocar el codigo que involucra tu pregunta.

Comment: Perdon, pero es que aun no hago el codigo, solo pregunto para darme una idea de como relizarlo.

Comment: Lee los links que te pase en el primer comentario.. aqui se pide que demuestres que intentaste y vengas con un problema concreto. Saludos.

Comment: @JosuaRamirez no es buena práctica conservar los datos en un Fragment, se deben volver a obtener para evitar memory leaks. Si estas descargando información podrías mejor guardarla en Base de datos y al requerir el fragment consultar esta información desde la base de datos.  Es importante agregues mas información de como esta estructurado tu proyecto, que formato de información descargas, etc.... revisa los enlaces que te proporciona gbianchi , es muy importante leer [ask] de lo contrario si no realizas una pregunta con la información necesaría probablemente no obtendrás la ayuda requerida.